# Erro upload - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, upload

Estou fazendo o upload de um arquivo csv, porém ele retorna o erro de extensão inválida, mesmo a extensão estando liberada. Fui buscar a causa do erro e descobri que é por causa de uma linha que está no arquivo.

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('erro', $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect(base_url() . 'updb/up_numeros/' . $tipo);
        exit;
    }
```

Entre a linhas do arquivo csv existe uma com o seguinte texto:

```
COLUNA 1              COLUNA 2
C TESTE - 6173        2
```

Quando eu excluo o linha ou incluo um espaço vazio ou qualquer outro caractere na coluna 1, o upload é realizado com sucesso.

Alguém tem ideia de onde pode estar o erro?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar o `allowed_types`.

Ex.:

```
    $configUpload['upload_path']   = $path;
    $configUpload['file_name']   = $descricao;
    $configUpload['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|pdf|zip|rar|doc|xls';
    $this->upload->initialize($configUpload);
```